# ReactToPdf library not working in my code

Tags: reactjs

This is my React code that contains **react-to-pdf** library. Its version is 0.0.14. I followed the instructions for the usage. I need help from experts

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import OfficerButton from '../Common/OfficerButton/OfficerButton'
import { CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core'
import { callChatGpt } from '../../utils/api'
import { chatGptTurboUrl, promptExample } from '../../utils/apiUrls'
import { OfficerInputField, OfficerSelect } from '../Common'
import logo from '../../assets/logo_officer.png'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import './TranslateSurvey.css'
import parse from 'html-react-parser'
import { LanguagesArray } from '../../utils/Constants/LanguagesArray'
import { ReactToPdf } from 'react-to-pdf'

const componentRef = React.createRef()
const options = {
  orientation: 'landscape',
  unit: 'in'
}
const TranslateSurvey = ({ notify }) => {
  TranslateSurvey.propTypes = {
    notify: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  const [translate, setTranslate] = useState('')
  const [transLang, setTransLang] = useState('')

  const [turboResult, setTurboResult] = useState('')
  const [chatSpinner, setChatSpinner] = useState(false)
  const generateChatGPT = async () => {
    if (translate.length > 0) {
      setChatSpinner(true)
      var keywords = translate.concat('\n Translate it as ', transLang)
      const res = await callChatGpt(chatGptTurboUrl, keywords)
      if (!res.isError) {
        setTurboResult(res.data.data.choices[0].message.content.trim().toString().replace(/\n/g, '<br />'))
        setChatSpinner(false)
      } else {
        setTurboResult(res.error.error.message)
        setChatSpinner(false)
      }
    } else {
      notify('Please add your survey!', 'warning', 1000)
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-lg-nowrap justify-content-around">
        <div className="translate-results">
          <div ref={componentRef}>
            <div className="results-title">Results</div>
            <div className="result-box">
              <div>{chatSpinner ? <CircularProgress /> : ''}</div>
              <div>{parse(turboResult)}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="pt-4 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
            <ReactToPdf targetRef={componentRef} filename="translatesurvey.pdf" options={options} scale={0.7}>
              {({ toPdf }) => (
                <button className="btn-export my-3" onClick={toPdf}>
                  Export
                </button>
              )}
            </ReactToPdf>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default TranslateSurvey
```

This page is not displayed due to the following code. When I put this code into the component, the page is not displayed anymore.

```
<ReactToPdf targetRef={componentRef} filename="translatesurvey.pdf" options={options} scale={0.7}>
  {({ toPdf }) => (
    <button className="btn-export my-3" onClick={toPdf}>
      Export
    </button>
  )}
</ReactToPdf>
```

**Error message**
[image: Error image]